# Select option value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select option value on ".color" click

```
<li class="gfield material_color_select">
    <label for="input_1_2" class="gfield_label"> Colour</label>
    <div class="ginput_container_select">
        <select class="gfield_select" id="input_1_2" ">
            <option value="--- Please select ---">--- Please select ---</option>
            <option value="Black"> Black</option>
            <option value="Blue"> Blue</option>
            <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

And I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".color").click(function(){
        $(".material_color_select .gfield_select").val('Black').attr('selected', true);
    });   
});
```

But it doesn`t work

Thanks

Comment: It should work, try removing `.attr('selected', true)`. `.attr('selected', true)` is not required. And when you want to use it, use it as `.attr('selected', 'selected')`.

Comment: you can get it in javascript too document.getElementById("input_1_2").options[select.selectedIndex].value

Comment: What means 'not working'? Is click event fired? Error in console? Etc...

Comment: where is the element `.color`?

Comment: `.val()`, called on the select element, will set which option is selected. When you say you want to select it, do you mean you want to move the focus to it? If so, use the `.focus()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `attr()` call, just `.val('Black')` will do it:

```
$(".color").click(function(){
    $(".material_color_select .gfield_select").val('Black');
});
```

Note that you will also need to remove the trailing space after the `value` attributes:

```
<select class="gfield_select" id="input_1_2">
    <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
</select>
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dh5cp8ss/)

Comment: That's correct but doesn't explain why OP's code isn't working then

Comment: @A.Wolff it didn't work due to the additional whitespace in the `value`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But there isn't as i can see it. You are taliking about text, right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff it was there in the original question - OP edited it out before the notification timeout.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh ok, really bad OP move then :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the below code for that:

```
$( "#input_1_2" ).val();
```

Or, if you want the selected field text, just use the below:

```
$( "#input_1_2 option:selected" ).text();
```